# comparing user input to 3 generated random number in java

Tags: java, random

So i want user to enter 3 numbers between 1-10 then the system will generate 3 random numbers then compare them. if they match one you get $250, match 2 $500. match 3 in order $1000, and $0 for no match.

So far i think i got the generator works (cant actually test it atm) but how do i compare them?

here is the code

```
import java.util.Random

public class lab3
{
    public static void main(String[] args
    {
        System.out.println("Enter three numbers between 1-10 ");

        System.out.println("Enter first guess: ");
        Int firstGuess= keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter second guess: ");
        Int secondGuess= keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter third guess: ");
        Int thirdGuess= keyboard.nextInt();

        Random rnd= new Random();
        for (int counter = 1; counter<= 3; ++counter) {
            int Lottery = rnd.nextInt(10);
            System.out.print("Generated numbers: " + counter + ": ");
        }
```

Comment: How much does it cost to play this game?

Comment: This code doesn't even compile for things like `Int firstGuess`, unbalanced braces and undefined variable `keyboard`.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the numbers (given by the user) in an Array. Then every time a number is generated, you check if that number is present in the array (with a "for" loop). At the first match, you increase a counter and generate the following random number, until you reach 3 iterations.

Comment: damn. thta sounds really confusing. sry. im rly new to this

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to do this is to store your 2x3 integer in 2 array :

```
int userInt[];
int randomInt[];
```

Then you push your number in your arrays

```
userInt[0] = keyboard.nextInt(); //...Etc
```

Finally use a double for loop to iterate over your two arrays :

```
for(int i= 0; i<userInt.size(); i++){
    for (int j =0; j<randomInt.size(); j++){
        if (userInt[i] == randomInt[j]){
            //Do your stuff here
```

Also, you may want to use a variable to store the number of positive match (i let you figure out how).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
int matchCount = 0;
for (int counter = 1; counter <= 3; ++counter) {
     int lottery = rnd.nextInt(10);
     System.out.print("Generated numbers: " + counter + ": ");
     if ((lottery == firstGuess) || (lottery == secondGuess) || (lottery == thirdGuess)) {
        matchCount++;
     }
  }
```

And then use matchCount to determine how much the player won.

Comment: I guess that on simple question like this one, it is more useful to give him hints (that will make him understand), rather than giving a valid solution (that he may not try to understand).

Answer (score 0):

You should add another variable that will hold how much money they earned after checking.

```
int moneyWon = 0;
```

Inside the for loop:

```
if(lottery == firstGuess || lottery == secondGuess || lottery == thirdGuess)            {
    if(moneyWon == 0){
        moneyWon = 250;
    }
    else{
        moneyWon = moneyWon * 2
    }
}
```

After the loop you can print something like this:

```
System.out.println("Your total is: $" + moneyWon);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Guess the number and win the prize:");
    System.out.println("FIRST TRY ====> $1,00,000");
    System.out.println("SECOND TRY ===> $50,000");
    System.out.println("LAST TRY =====> $10,000");
    System.out.println("Guess the Number between 0 to 10(First)");
    int guess= keyboard.nextInt();

    Random rnd= new Random();
    int lotteryNumber = rnd.nextInt(10);
    if(lotteryNumber == guess){
        System.out.println("Your guess is true.");
        System.out.println("Congratulation!!! You won ---$1,00,000---");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your Guess is not true.");
        System.out.println("Guess the Number between 0 to 10(Second)");
        int guess1= keyboard.nextInt();
        if(lotteryNumber== guess1) {
            System.out.println("Your Second Guess is true.");
            System.out.println("Congratulation!!!  You won ---$50,000---");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your Guess is not true.");
            System.out.println("Guess the Number between 0 to 10(Third)");
            int guess2= keyboard.nextInt();
            if(lotteryNumber == guess2) {
                System.out.println("Your Third guess is true.");
                System.out.println("Congratulation!!!   You won ---$10,000---");
            } else {
                System.out.println("TRY AGAIN..");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Lottery Number is = " + lotteryNumber);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for your answer. Rather than just posting a block of code, can you give a short explanation to what the issue is you solved and how you solved it? This will help people who find this question in the future to better understand the issue and how to deal with it.